# "Aftersend" event for Ajax calls?

Tags: php, ajax

$.ajax calls a PHP page that perform many operations.
I want my users can close the page after the PHP script received the request.

How do I know when the script has received the request?

Something like...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/my-huge-script", 
    type: "POST",
    ...
    ...
    afterSend: function(){
        alert('The script has received the request. You can close the browser.');
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

### UPDATE

I tried:

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/huge-page",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
        ... LARGE DATA! (base64 file)
    },
    success: function() {
        alert('The script has received the request. You can close the browser.')
    }
})
```

HUGE-PAGE.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('Success' => "get it"));

... MANY operations ...

?>
```

**But 'success' fires only at the end of the PHP script..**

The $_POST data that are sent to the PHP page vary in size, for this reason I want users to know when the request was done... without waiting the end of the PHP script.

Comment: I don't think there's a function called `afterSend`, there's `error` and `success`.

Answer (score 1):

well, you can print out some `json` on your `huge.php` page.

on top of your page you can do something like that

```
echo json_encode(array('succes' => "get it"));
```

and you should use:

```
success: function(response){
    //...
}
```

and in your `success` function in `ajax` call, check if you get this message, and add `alert` there after that.

Comment: what does json have to do with anything?

Comment: nothing, just an indication to `ajax` call that response received.

Comment: but if you're in the success function you know the response was received, no matter what it returns

Comment: yes, as mentioned just an indication, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

try your HUGE-PAGE.php file:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    // operations should before output 
    // so =>
     ... MANY operations ...
    // output at end of the file and exit()
    // so => 
    echo json_encode(array('Success' => "get it"));
    exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Jquery ajax's always() callback function will work for you. See the example code below.

```
 var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
   alert( "success" );
 })

 .always(function() {
   alert( "complete" );
  });
```

> jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) {
>   }); An alternative construct to the complete callback option, the
>   .always() method replaces the deprecated .complete() method.
>
> In response to a successful request, the function's arguments are the
>   same as those of .done(): data, textStatus, and the jqXHR object. For
>   failed requests the arguments are the same as those of .fail(): the
>   jqXHR object, textStatus, and errorThrown. Refer to deferred.always()
>   for implementation details.

Just a reminder  the success callback method is depreciated ,You need to use .done() instead of success() callback function.

Comment: Alert "success" and "complete" always at the end of the PHP script.. not at the end of the request (right after the PHP script starts to perform the operations)